# Como passar dados de uma tabela para outra com checkbox?

Tags: angularjs

[image: Como passar itens de uma tabela para outra com check bix]

Olá, pessoal. Sou novo em programação Web e estou atualmente estudando alguns conceitos de Angular. Meu problema é o seguinte: passar os itens selecionados de uma tabela, por checkbox, para uma outra tabela. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Muito obrigado!

Comment: Você pode colocar o código que tem até então como exemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você só precisa filtrar a segunda tabela de acordo com o atributo selecionado na primeira:

```js
angular
  .module('ModuloTabelas', [])
  .controller('ControllerTabelas', ControllerTabelas);

ControllerTabelas.$inject = [];

function ControllerTabelas() {
  var tabelas = this;
  tabelas.dados = [];

  iniciar();

  function iniciar() {
    tabelas.dados.push({
      codigo: 1,
      selecionado: false,
      texto: 'opcao 1'
    });
    tabelas.dados.push({
      codigo: 2,
      selecionado: false,
      texto: 'opcao 2'
    });
    tabelas.dados.push({
      codigo: 3,
      selecionado: false,
      texto: 'opcao 3'
    });
    tabelas.dados.push({
      codigo: 4,
      selecionado: false,
      texto: 'opcao 4'
    });
    tabelas.dados.push({
      codigo: 5,
      selecionado: false,
      texto: 'opcao 5'
    });
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr {
  height: 37px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ModuloTabelas">
  <div ng-controller="ControllerTabelas as tabelas">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="3">
            Opções
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
          </th>
          <th>
            Código
          </th>
          <th>
            Texto
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="linhaTb1 in tabelas.dados track by linhaTb1.codigo">
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="linhaTb1.selecionado" />
          </td>
          <td>
            {{linhaTb1.codigo}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{linhaTb1.texto}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="3">
            Filtradas
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Código
          </th>
          <th>
            Texto
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="linhaTb2 in tabelas.dados | filter: {selecionado: true} track by linhaTb2.codigo">
          <td>
            {{linhaTb2.codigo}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{linhaTb2.texto}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Poxa vida, era mais simples do que pensei. Pra quem está iniciando, às vezes parece complicado. Muito obrigado, Sorack. Vai me ajudar bastante. Abraços!